# aggregation of tables with array columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table 1

| berechtigen_ids: _int4 |
| --- |
| {1,2,3} |
| {1} |
| {2} |

Table 2

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Karl |
| 2 | Fritz |
| 3 | Chlodwig |

View 3

| berechtigte |
| --- |
| Karl, Fritz, Chlodwig |
| Karl |
| Fritz |

I have table 1 and table 2, I want to achieve view 3. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lateral join or subquery:

```
select (select string_agg(t2.name, ', ')
        from table2 t2
        where t2.id = any(t1. berechtigen_ids)
       ) as names
from table1 t1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=278a07aace91b77988dcb9877b3bbf7d) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that this does not use aggregation, so if two rows have the same ids, there are still two rows in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```sql
select string_agg(name, ', ') as berechtigte
from table2 t2
join table1 t1
on t2.id = any(t1.berechtigen_ids)
group by berechtigen_ids
```

Though this code won't run properly if you have duplcates in the `table1`. If that's the case I would suggest adding a new column `id` in the `table1` and grouping by it.